# Phonegap/Jquery Button Back

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 1.9 on Android. My index.html page has 2 divs, named page1 and page 2.

Page 1 contains some inputs and a CALC button. Page 2 contains the results in plain text and a Back and Reset button

The flow between the pages, the back actions and the results are both fine at first sight.
My problem is after I press the back button, I change the value on the `hight1` input box and press `CALC` button. But the result is the old value for some weird reason...any ideas? is there any param for recalc or history I should change?

Here is what I have:

**index.html**

```
<div id="Page1">
    <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="hight1" value="0" min="0" max="800"/>m
    <div data-role="button" onclick="calcResults();">
        Calc
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Page2">
    <strong id="hight2">&nbsp;</strong>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" onclick="resetApp();">Reset</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Go Back</a>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
function calcSimpleResultActionHandler (result) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    $('#hight2').html(obj.hight1);
    $.mobile.changePage("#Page2");
}
function calcResults() {
    var sentData = new Array();
    var calcResultActionHandler;
    calcResultActionHandler = calcSimpleResultActionHandler;
    sentData[0] = $( "#hight1" ).val();
    HandleActionsPlugin.calc( calcResultActionHandler, actionErrorHandler, sentData);   
}
function resetapp() {
    $('#hight1').val('0');
}
var HandleActionsPlugin = { 
        saveStep1: function (success, fail, resultType) { 
            return cordova.exec( success, fail, 
                    "HandlePhoneActions", 
                    "calc", resultType); 
};
function actionErrorHandler (error) { 

    $('#responseData').css('color', 'red');
    $('#responseData').html("Dammit:\r\n "+error+"");
    $("#actionResponsePopup").popup( "open" );
}
```

}

**HandlePhoneActions.java**

```
private static final String CALC= "calc"; 
@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        if (CALC.equals(action)) {
            structure.sethight1(args.getString(0));
        }
        JSONObject resObj  = new JSONObject();
        resObj.put("hight1", structure.gethight1());
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, resObj);
}
```

**UPDATED**: second id was misspelled, thank you Omar for pointing it out

**UPDATED**: added some more code as requested by Ani

Comment: you have two element with the same id `hight1`. this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you Omar for your comment but that id issue does not happen in my real code.The code posted just mimics the real code logic that I'm trying to fix. I can't post the real code since the real one has 3000 lines.

Comment: oh ok, you want to reset slider? which version are you using of jQM?

Comment: You probably should add more details of your code, because if the only thing you are doing in `calcResults()` is changing page, then it is the expected behavior that it will have the old values.  You need to perform the math to update the divs in the second page before you transition to it

Comment: jQM = jQuery Mobile, `data-role=button` and `data-rel=back` are used in jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Sory Omar, I'm using jquery 1.7.2 and jquery mobile 1.2.1